# Two different definitions for current?

Tags: electric-current

I don't really get the definition and am confused in these two not knowing which is correct:

- Suppose I took an cross-sectional area between the wire. I start my stopwatch. At $t=1sec$ I see that $1 C$ charge passes through the cross- sectional area $A$. At $t=10sec$ I see that $1C$ of charge passes through $A$. So $I_{avg}$=0
  Here I assume that $I {\displaystyle \equiv }$ slope of $Q-t$ graph.
- Now I count the **total** charge that passes through $A$ in from $t=1s$ till $t=10$ and divide the amount obtained by $9$. In this case $I \neq 0 $.

I am pretty sure that the first definition is correct, but then I get problem(when we derive $\vec{J}=\vec{I}/A$) interpreting $I=nqv_dA$ in which It is defined as the **total** charge that is present physically between two cross sections with distance between them being $ \Delta{x} $. I have $3$ problems with this:

$(1)$ This measures the amount of **total** charge present between two cross sections and not the **change** in charge.**This is a different definition of current?**

$(2)$ All of a sudden we have two cross sectional areas and volume comes into play

$(3)$ Shouldn't $ \Delta {x} \to 0 $

Comment: It's not clear to me if you mean that 1 C passed through the wire between t=0 and t=10, or if 1 C passed through the wire in an instant at t=10? Also in your first scenario of the total charts that passed is 2 C I don't see how you calculated an average current of 0.

Comment: @thephoton I am time equal to 1 second one coulomb of passes through the cross section and at time equal to 10 seconds one coulomb of charge passing through the cross section

Comment: Do you know about the Dirac delta function?

Comment: @thephoton No,just a highschooler:)

Comment: @thephoton I am sure there is a simpler solution

Comment: It will be a while before I am at a proper keyboard to give you a proper answer. Maybe someone else can give you a good answer before then.

Comment: @thephoton That's fine. Still thank you

Comment: How did you arrive at an average current of 0 in the first case?

Comment: @Steeven $Q(t=1)=1C$ and $Q(t=10)=1C$ . So $\Delta{Q}=0$. I am relatively new to this whole current stuff , so please correct me if i have made a mistake somewhere

Comment: @saketkumar Why are you subtracting those two charges? Shouldn't you be adding them? $\Delta Q = 2 \,\textrm{C}$

Comment: @ArturodonJuan I though $\Delta{f(t)} = f(t_2) -  f(t_1)$

Comment: @ArturodonJuan Current is **not** the slope of q-t graph?

Comment: @saketkumar It seems you are mixing up formulas and applying them incorrectly. Ignore that formula for a moment and consider the following: if at $t=1$ I give you one apple, and then at $t=10$ I give you another apple, how many apples have I given you? Obviously the answer is $2$ apples! The exact same logic applies here

Comment: @saketkumar Current is indeed the slope of the $q$-$t$ graph. But you must ask yourself, what exactly is $q$? What does that symbol mean in this context?

Comment: @ArturodonJuan Is $q$ the charge that has moved **across** the cross section area ? Only then would it make sense as I would end up with $2C$ charge across the $CSA$(cross sectional area)

Comment: @ArturodonJuan but what does it mean that $1C$ has of charge has flon through $CSA$ **at** $t=1$

Comment: @saketkumar Yes, it is the amount of charge that has moved across the cross section. The total charge that has passed is $2\,\textrm{C}$.

Comment: @saketkumar If a charge passes $A$ **at** $t=1$, that means before $t=1$ the charge was on one side, and after $t=1$ the charge was on the other side. So at $t=1-\frac{\Delta t}{2}$ the charge was on one side, and at $t=1+\frac{\Delta t}{2}$ it was on the other side, no matter how small $\Delta t$ is. The instantaneous current at $t=1$ was therefore $I(t=1)=\lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0} \Delta Q / \Delta t\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan So should the current for $t = [0,10]$ be $0.1A$ as **at**=10 sec the charge hasn't yet crosses the CSA. As at t=10 sec you haven't giving me an apple rather you are giving it to me

Comment: @saketkumar Pretty much, yes. We should better say, that the average current over the interval $t\in(0,10)$, which does not include $t=10$, is $0.1\,\textrm{A}$.

Comment: @ArturodonJuan Thank you for clearing my silly doubts as my teachers simply reject them for being silly or start to scold us.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124262/discussion-between-saket-kumar-and-arturo-don-juan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current is amount of charge passing through a cross-sectional area per unit time. Consider a cross-sectional area $A$. Suppose in a time period $\Delta t$ you measure a total amount of charge $\Delta Q$ passing through the cross-sectional area. Then

$$I_{\textrm{avg}}\equiv\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}$$

In your example, a $1\,\textrm{C}$ of charge passes at $t=1\,\textrm{s}$, and another $1\,\textrm{C}$ of charge passes at $t=10\,\textrm{s}$. Therefore, within the time interval $t\in[0\,\textrm{s},10\,\textrm{s}]$, a total of $\Delta Q = 2\,\textrm{C}$ has passed, so the average current over this time interval is:

$$I_{\textrm{avg}}=\frac{2\,\textrm{C}}{10\,\textrm{s}}=0.2\,\textrm{A}$$

If instead you ask, what is the average current over the time interval $t\in[1\,\textrm{s},10\,\textrm{s}]$? The answer to that is:

$$I_{\textrm{avg}}=\frac{2\,\textrm{C}}{9\,\textrm{s}}=\frac 2 9 \,\textrm{A}$$

Usually we define the **current** to be the instantaneous rate of charge flow, i.e.

$$I(t)\equiv \lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}$$

So when we say the value of the current **at** a particular time $t$, what we mean is, measure the amount of charge that passes through $A$ between $t$ and $t+\Delta t$ where $\Delta t$ is a super small number, and then calculate $I(t)=\Delta Q / \Delta t$. If a small point of charge $Q$ passes at **exactly** $t=t_0$, then the current is infinity!

We can derive the average current over a time interval $t\in [t_1,t_2]$:

$$
\begin{align}
I_{\textrm{avg}}&=\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2} I(t)\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\Delta Q
\end{align}$$